# How to create Shortcut-Context-Menu-Handler for Android

Tags: android, click, contextmenu, handler, long-click

When clicking on a file in the filesystem in Android (long click) a popup menu appears, just like the Windows-right-click-menu. Is there any way to add a menu item, referencing my app?

For Windows it would look like this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> When clicking on a file in the filesystem in Android (long click) a popup menu appears, just like the Windows-right-click-menu.

There is no file manager in Android. You may be thinking of some third-party file manager that you installed or that was part of your device's firmware.

> Is there any way to add a menu item, referencing my app?

You would have to find the author of the file manager in question and ask them.